# How to skip source maps in development?

Tags: javascript, jspm

I have a simple little application where I'm playing around with jspm and angular. It currently takes almost a few seconds to pull up the screen. My hypothesis is that I can speed it up significantly by disabling the generation of sourcemaps that are embedded as data-urls in the scripts generated by jspm.

How do I disable them to test my hypothesis?

Again, this is the standard compilation-in-browser workflow, not a production build-on-server one. I assume I need to add something to `configure.js` but what?

Comment: Hi, I've answered below. Please let me know about your findings in regards to loading speed. Thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable source maps in Babel setting the `sourceMaps` option to false:

```
System.config({
  "baseURL": "/src",
  "transpiler": "babel",
  "babelOptions": {
      "sourceMaps":"false"
  });
```

But you will still get `system.js.map` and the `es6-module-loader.js.map` files in the browser.